# What is the MySQL equivalent of MS-SQL's .mdf and .ldf file extensions?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to submit a new server request to my server management group to create a MySQL server. One of the fields required is to list file extensions which need to be excluded during commvault backups. All of our other database servers use MS SQL, and I know that the active DB files (.mdf and .ldf) need to be excldued.

What is the MySQL equivalent to these active db file extensions? Normally I'm a programmer who doesn't deal with this but today I was assigned this task and I'm stuck at this last step.

Edit: If it would be easier to answer, what are the dump file equivalents? MS SQL uses .bak and .trn, which are backed up here.

Thanks for your help...google searches are just loaded with people looking to convert these files to MySQL, so that hasn't been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the storage engine you are planning to use.
For MyISAM this would be `.frm` (table files), `.MYD` (data files) and `.MYI` (index files).
If you are using a different storage engine like InnoDB this will be different.
You can find this out by checking the documentation of the storage engine you are going to use.
You will also want to exclude some other files most likely (again depending on your setup: binlogs, relaylogs, etc.).

Best would be to setup this database first in a test environment and check what your application actually uses.

Comment: (same comment as the one on the other answer) I never realized the question "which file extensions SHOULD i back up?" would be more realistic (and concise). Can you check the edit I made to my question dealing with backup files? Is there an equivalent to the .bak and .trn files that I currently back up in MS SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to depend on your Storage Engine. For MyISAM/INNODB the files are

.MYD  for data files
.MYI  for index files
.frm  for table format files

You might be better off though excluding the entire MySQL directory and manually pushing your database backups once they're complete.

Comment: I never realized the question "which file extensions SHOULD i back up?" would be more realistic (and concise). Can you check the edit I made to my question dealing with backup files? Is there an equivalent to the .bak and .trn files that I currently back up in MS SQL?

Comment: The backup files and log files will be whatever you name them. MySQL doesn't really care about the extension. You could keep them uniform with the MSSQL extensions just to make life easy.

Comment: The binlog files will have a numeric extension.